# Using Integer Variable as Index in scanf

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I'm trying to do the below in my function but keep getting a segmentation fault error. It's failing when I'm trying to use `[iModify - 1]` as my index.

Can you not use an int variable calculation as an index in C?

```
int modify(pb *PhoneBook)
{
   int x;
   int iModify = 0;
   char name_num[] = {'\0'};
   print(PhoneBook);
   printf("\nWhich entry would you like to modify? ");
   scanf("%d", &iModify);
   printf("\niModify - 1: %d\n", iModify - 1);

   printf("\nModify name or number? ");
   scanf("%s", name_num);
   convert_u(name_num);
   if (strcmp(name_num, "NAME") == 0) {
      printf("\nEnter new name: ");
      scanf("%s %s", PhoneBook[iModify - 1].cFirstName, PhoneBook[iModify - 1].cLastName); //fails here
   }
   else if (strcmp(name_num, "NUMBER") == 0) {
      printf("\nEnter new number: ");
      scanf("%s", PhoneBook[iModify - 1].cNumber); //also fails here
   }
}
```

Comment: 1. Check the return values from `scanf` 2. `scanf("%s", name_num);` - The array `name_num` is only one character!

Comment: 3. don't use scanf with plain %s : specify the max width

Comment: @Veltas: You can specify a max. field width for the string.

Comment: @Olaf meant to imply that with "plain"

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is

```
 char name_num[] = {'\0'};
```

here, `name_num` is having a length of 1 `char`, which will not be sufficient for holding a *string* at a later point. So, when you do

```
scanf("%s", name_num);
```

you're essentially writing out of bound which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Reference: `C11`, chapter §6.7.9

> If an array of unknown size is initialized, its size is determined by the largest indexed
>   element with an explicit initializer. [...]

To compare with your code, `name_num` is an array of unknown size which is being initialized by only a single element in a brace enclosed initializer, so the size of the array will be 1.

Solution:  You have to mention the size explicitly at the time of definition. You'll be needing something like

```
char name_num[32] = {'\0'};     //32 is just for example purpose
....
scanf("%31s", name_num);  // make sure longer inputs don't blow up the buffer
```

or similar.

---

Having said that, please notice your `int modify()` function **does not** `return` any value. If the returned value is used in the caller, it will again invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @SouravGhosh - thanks! I was overlooking that name_num character length. This works.

Answer (score 0):

You have used `char name_num[] = {'\0'};` in your code. `name_num` has the length of 1 `char`, which is too short to hold a string later.

Therefore, you are writing out-of-bounds when you read `name_num`.